# How to determine conditions in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a file that looks like this:

[image: here]

And I have a file that looks like this:

[image]

So If C24 is Yes then E25 needs a value (from drop down – otherwise it needs an error message to detail the spec). Equally if C24 is No or blank then E25 must also be blank (or show error message)

Same is also true for C22 and E22

How can I create it too? I also need to add a button at the bottom to export to pdf.

Comment: Example data should be **in the question** not some external link. Please [edit] and fix this.

Comment: I've embedded all of your images in the question, but it isn't clear how the one you just added relates to the question.  That aside, please note that the site is not a free coding service.  If you try to tackle this yourself and run into problems, people here can help clarify where you're going wrong if you include your formulas.

Comment: You should be able to handle the "Yes"/"No" stuff with Conditional Formatting.